# How to troubleshot: IpcThreadState log spam / system_server eating battery

Tags: battery, logging

The last days, i encounter the issue of my phone draining its battery fast (about 10-15%/h when idle).

I'm trying to see what's happening, there are no unusual or suspicious alarms or wake locks.

system_server has took a large slate of the phones cpu processing time (according to BetterBatteryStats), it isn't entering deep sleep.

According to logcat that doesn't wonder me - every 50ms a lot of [E] error log lines are logged.

they are

```
*tr[0]=value1: value2,
*tr[1]=value1: value2,
...
*tr[9]=value1: value2,
*mIn.mData[2]=value1: value2
...
*mIn.mData[11]=value1: value2,
```

i suspect value1 to be pointer adresses, and value2 to be values - value2 does match between most of the logged lines, and also between tr and mData  (so tr[0].value2 == mIn.mData[2].value2 )

i know that IpcThreadState is related to the android binder ipc mechanism, but i don't really find something logging out lines like that in the repositories i've found.

Ah: Could be related: my phone is a SM-G850F Build KTU84P.G850FXXU2BNK3 Stock Firmware, rooted.

And the Question I've got is: how can i find out what is causing this extensive spam (i guess the binder is going circles due to some misbehaving application?), without doing a factory reset and reinstalling applications one by one...

Comment: Did you find out anything about this? I have a customer (user of my Android app) who sent me a system log and I see tens of thousands of these entries in that log as well. The customer has Samsung Galaxy s5 mini SMG800F phone.

Comment: I did a wipe data and reinstalled everything, this fixed it till now... 

I guess its a modification by Samsung that produces this exact entries (didn't find log lines like this in AOSP kernel source), but i don't know the root cause

Comment: Thank you! Guess I should advise this to my customer as well. I assume you did a "factory reset" of your device, right?